# Fake: Use MSBuild version 16 (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: visual-studio, f#-fake

We have a several years old fsx/FAKE file that start up MSBuild version 14 (VisualStudio 2015) in the line

`MSBuild null "Build" ["Configuration", buildMode] ["./Spider80.sln"]`.

How do we make FAKE use MSBuild from Visual Studio 2019/MSBuild version 16 instead?

(For the older versions of our product, we still need to use Visual Studio 2015, so we may not uninstall VS 2015).

Comment: PS. We use FAKE version 4.61.0.  Should we install a newer version ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the msbuild tools version, i.e.

```
let setParams defaults =
    { defaults with
        ToolsVersion = Some("16.0")
    }
```

Comment: Have already tried that, including changing
`MSBuild null "Build" ["Configuration", buildMode] ["./Spider80.sln"]`

to

`MSBuild setParams "Build" ["Configuration", buildMode] ["./Spider80.sln"]`

But perhaps I should have changed to:


`MSBuild defaults "Build" ["Configuration", buildMode] ["./Spider80.sln"]`   ?


Or perhaps I should not have changed the MSBuild-line at all?

Comment: seen this?: https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/issues/1442. Potentially just try the workaround then?